# Different operations for different columns in a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a square `numpy` matrix with `0` and `1` and I have to do different operations according to the column.

If the column contains all `0` I have to replace these `0` with `1/number_of_the_colomns` (i use the command `matrix.shape[1]`) , else (if colomn doesn't contain all `0`) i have to divide each element by the sum of the colomn.

In essence, after these operations the sum of each colomn must be `1`.

I try this but i have error in the third line: `index returns 3-dim structure`

```
a=numpy.nonzero(out_degree)
b=numpy.where(out_degree==0)
graph[:,b]=1/graph.shape[0]
graph[:,a]=graph/out_degree
```

`graph` is the `numpy matrix`, `out_degree` is a `vector` that contains the `sum` of each colomn

I have to use `numpy` without loop to save time.

Comment: Hi, you need to be more specific with your question (i.e. what is the operation that you want to perform on your matrix). Do check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok, i edit the question :D

Comment: "after these operations the sum of each colomn may be 0(if all elements of the colomn are 0)" this doesn't match the previous description "If the column contains all 0 I have to replace these 0 with 1/number_of_the_colomns "

Comment: you're right, i edited ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A start would be:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

M, N = 5, 4
a = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], size=(M, N), p=[0.6, 0.2, 0.2]).astype(float)

print(a)

a_inds = np.where(~a.any(axis=0))[0]
b_inds = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(N), a_inds, assume_unique=True)
b_col_sums = np.sum(a[:, b_inds], axis=0)
a[:, a_inds] = 1 / N
a[:, b_inds] /= b_col_sums

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]
[[ 0.25        0.33333333  0.25        0.        ]
 [ 0.25        0.          0.25        0.        ]
 [ 0.25        0.          0.25        0.5       ]
 [ 0.25        0.66666667  0.25        0.5       ]
 [ 0.25        0.          0.25        0.        ]]
```

This should be easy to read and of medium performance. It's probably not the fastest because of a lot of fancy-indexing.

It also does not check the problematic cases of *divide by zero* (not part of your specification)!

**Edit:** OP is only interested in square-arrays, so the following is to be ignored!

You state: `In essence, after these operations the sum of each colomn must be 1.` and give the operation: `have to replace these 0 with 1/number_of_the_columns`, which is a contradiction. Maybe you need to replace N with M in `a[:, a_inds] = 1 / N`.

Then you obtain:

```
[[ 0.2         0.33333333  0.2         0.        ]
 [ 0.2         0.          0.2         0.        ]
 [ 0.2         0.          0.2         0.5       ]
 [ 0.2         0.66666667  0.2         0.5       ]
 [ 0.2         0.          0.2         0.        ]]
```

Comment: It's correct your previous answer because if i have all `0` in a colomn i have to replace all `0` with `1/number_of_cols` (or rows, it's the same because is square). 
Instead, if i don't have all `0` in a colomn (so i have some `0` and some `1`), i need to divide each `1`(because the matrix is composed of `0` and `1`) by the sum of the colomn before the division

Comment: Ok. The square-characteristic was not mentioned (and my example is not square).

Comment: yes, i edited my question after your answer :D thank you, i have reasonable result with your method. The division by zero is excluded with your method

Comment: Division by zero can happen if there are negative values. But it seems that's also not the case (probabilities).

Answer (score 0):

You can check for nonzero elements otherwise just sum it.

```
for col in range(a.shape[1]):
    if np.any(a[:, col]):
        a[:, col] /= np.sum(a[:, col])
    else:
        a[:, col] = 1/a.shape[1]
```